# Is it possible to link another organization into Azure so that the new domain email accounts don't get added as guests in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

I'm developing an application that requires us to use Microsoft Graph API to create Teams meetings for users. This is obviously only possible with tenant domain email accounts (not guests) as you cannot do it on behalf of the user. Is it possible that I can add a new domain/organization to it so any of the new domain email addresses can be used to create meetings (don't get added as guests)?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-organization

Comment: @matt sharp did a link provided by Carl Zhao is helpful for you please confirm.

Comment: Not sure sorry, still looking into it - will return a response shortly

Comment: Im looking to add an existing office365 into our Azure so that I can action Teams on behalf of the users (got full admin rights to this other office365) - not sure governance is that

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a new domain but you can add user's from another tenant as guest only, It is by design.